# Is there a way to add a column to a table without affecting performance?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, ddl

How do you add a column to a table in production without affecting its performance?  Or is this impossible?  I'm asking about Postgres.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are talking about ?

Comment: I updated my question.  I'm curious if about Oracle, MySQL and SQL Server too.

Comment: @Propulsion if the question is not only about Postgres, please update it, adding that in the question text.

Answer (score 4):

For Postgres, adding a column *without* a default value is essentially a no-op as only the catalog tables get rewritten.

Apart from the short exclusive(!) lock there is no performance impact.

Although that lock is only held for a very short time, *getting* the lock on a busy system might be a problem because **all** open transactions and queries need to be finished before this lock can be acquired. And of course you need to make sure that the DDL gets committed immediately, because every access (including read-only selects) will be blocked until the `alter table` is committed.

Adding a column *with* a default value is a different thing though - that *will* affect performance because it is updating all existing rows with the default value.

If I'm not mistaken MySQL always rewrites the full table (and all indexes) if you add (or drop) a column (but it's been a while since I used MySQL so things could have changed).

Oracle works the same as Postgres.

I don't know about SQL Server, but I would be surprised if it did it differently.

Comment: In recent versions of SQL-Server, adding a column with a default is a very fast operation: http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/

Comment: On a busy Postgres system adding a column might never get through. I've had to firewall out all clients to get the exclusive lock required. By contrast, SQL Server blocks new locks until the `alter` has gone through. Surprisingly different behavior!